# .insertBefore Jquery not working?

Tags: jquery

I have put together a simple piece of Jquery that upon clicking an anchor tag (Advanced Search) toggles more content below it and moves the search button, everything works as expected except that when I toggle back to the elements original layout the search button does not move back.. bit stumped as to why

I have put it in a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/fn9E8/1

and here is my Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hiddenSearch').hide();
    $('#aSearch').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#hiddenSearch').slideToggle();
        if ($('#hiddenSearch').is(':visible')) {
            $('#searchButton').insertAfter('#last')
        } else {
            $('#searchButton').insertBefore('#aSearch')
        }
    });
});
```

What am i missing?

Thanks

Comment: it's because the `$('#hiddenSearch')` is still visible and not fully hidden yet since it's still sliding..

Comment: Dont forget to correct your closing `input` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put that code into `slideToggle`'s callback to ensure that the 'advanced search' panel has been fully revealed/hidden:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hiddenSearch').hide();
    $('#aSearch').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#hiddenSearch').slideToggle(function() {
            if ($('#hiddenSearch').is(':visible')) {
                $('#searchButton').insertAfter('#last')
            } else {
                $('#searchButton').insertBefore('#aSearch')
            }
        });

    }); //a#search click function
}); // document function​
```